# Which type of adverbial is “ about this policy”?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

“I will think again about this policy.”  In my view, “about this policy” is a preposition phrase, functioning as an adverbial. But I don’t know which type of adverbial this phrase is.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! To write you a useful answer, it might help if you add some more detail about your difficulty: what resources you've already looked at or what led you to the question. Try reading the message "[Details, please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/6700)" to get some more ideas for how you might clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks for your warm tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, [**about**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/about) is a preposition:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **4 a** : with regard to : CONCERNING
>   spoke *about* his past
>   **4 b** : concerned with
>   **4 c** : fundamentally concerned with or directed toward
>   … poker is *about* money.
>   — David Mamet

In short, the sentence could be rephrased as:

> I will think again ***concerning*** *this policy*.

---

This isn't an adverbial phrase. If it were, it would be explaining *how* you were you thinking, but it isn't.

What it's doing is describing the object of your thought, which is something different.

It's the same type of sentence as this:

> I'm going to jump ***onto*** *the stool*.

In that sentence, *onto the stool* is not acting adverbially, it's a simple prepositional phrase.

---

The following would be examples of adverbial phrases:

> I will think again ***with alacrity*** <sup>a preposition at the start of an adverbial phrase</sup>
> about this policy <sup>a simple prepositional phrase.</sup>
>
> I'm going to jump ***in a clumsy fashion*** <sup>a preposition at the start of an adverbial phrase</sup>
> onto the stool <sup>a simple prepositional phrase.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the OP is asking a question specifically about CGEL terminology, so an analysis in terms of traditional terminology might not answer it. If it weren't for that, I wouldn't hesitate to give this answer a +1.

Answer (score 0):

> *I will think again* [*about this policy*].

You are partly right: syntactically, "about this policy" is a preposition phrase, but it's not an adjunct (your adverbial).

The PP functions as complement of "think", the item that licenses (specifically requires or permits) it.